# Ads Management API multi account management

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am creating a Facebook app for providing insight into companies ad accounts, and I need to be able to have access to multiple accounts. Before I get started I want to make sure I can manage multiple companies Ad Accounts and report on them.

Do I need to use Facebook's "Ads Management API" along side of the "Ad Insights API"? And will either API provide multi account access?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know the Ads API allows you multi account access. For example, if you look at the [Facebook Python SDK Readme](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk), they give an example of using multiple accounts. I've included the relevant code below:

```
my_app_id = '<APP_ID>'
my_app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>'
my_access_token_1 = '<ACCESS_TOKEN_1>'
my_access_token_2 = '<ACCESS_TOKEN_2>'

session1 = FacebookSession(
    my_app_id,
    my_app_secret,
    my_access_token_1,
)

session2 = FacebookSession(
    my_app_id,
    my_app_secret,
    my_access_token_2,
)

api1 = FacebookAdsApi(session1)
api2 = FacebookAdsApi(session2)
```

Comment: Just want to clarify - in adwords, they have whats called an mcc account, which is basically a container account for agencies that is linked to client accounts - is there a similar abstraction for Facebook, or can I count on just having an access token per account?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest.